# Looping datatable within a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, c#-4.0

I had a stored procedure which has to be input with more than 8000 rows at a single button click that is used to close the daily attendance of employees.

I plan to send the input to stored procedure as datatable rather than sending it as row by row each time

I managed to create a table type user-defined type  and used a parameter with that user-defined type as input parameter

```
  USE [ATCHRM.MDF]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedTableType [dbo].[employeeswipedclose123]    Script Date: 12/11/2012 12:04:34 ******/
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[employeeswipedclose123] AS TABLE(
    [empid] [int] NULL,
    [datetoday] [datetime] NULL,
    [Swipepk] [int] NULL
)
GO
  CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CloseAttendance (@closingemployee dbo.employeeswipedclose123 READONLY )
AS
BEGIN

   MERGE EmployeSwipeDaily_tbl AS Target

   USING @closingemployee AS Source

   ON (Target.empid = Source.empid) and (Target.Date = Source.datetoday)

   WHEN MATCHED THEN 
       BEGIN 
           UPDATE    Target
            SET Target. IsCompleted = N'Y'
             WHERE     (Source.swipePK = Target.Swipepk) AND (Source.empid = Target.empid) AND (Target.Date = Source.datetoday)   

         WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN

       INSERT INTO Target
       (empid, Swipin, SwipeOut, Date, Duration, deviceid, InStatus, Outstatus, Invalue, OutValue, IsCompleted, CompletedDate)
        VALUES     (@empid, CONVERT(DATETIME, ' 00:00:00', 102), CONVERT(DATETIME, ' 00:00:00', 102),@datetoday, CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                      ' 00:00:00', 102), 0, N'A', N'A', 0, 0, N'Y',(select GETDATE()) )

END


GO
```

but now what I want is inside the stored procedure I want to loop the `Datatable` and check a condition

eg  like this

```
for(int i=0 ;i<dt.count;i++)
{
   if(dt.rows[i][swipepk]==0)
   {
       insert into employe swipe tbl()
   }
   else 
   {
       update employee tbl
   }
}
```

Can anyone suggest a better solution to loop a datatable in a stored procedure?

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to do with the data in the table `dbo.Employeedata`? are you trying to merging data? There might be an easy solution for this instead.

Comment: Since you're on SQL Server 2008 - use the `MERGE` statement ! That's **exactly** the scenario for the `MERGE` statement - insert new rows and update existing ones...

Comment: that employe table is a input parameter only.... when the users give a button click..the datafrom a grid view is captured  and passed to Stored procedure via the @closingemployee .....

Comment: also inside the stored  procedure it will check third column of @closingemployee ... (swipepk) is 0 or not if zero it has to enter a new row in one table named employeeswipetable with a set of predetermined values...else only update the employeeswipetable  as closed

Comment: If we go with this, if I have invalid data for single row then overall sproc will be failed right? I am facing same issue. is there any way to avoid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're on SQL Server 2008 - this is **exactly** the scenario for using the `MERGE` statement! No looping or anything needed - just a single `MERGE` statement will do!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CloseAttendance (@closingemployee dbo.Employeedata READONLY)
BEGIN
   -- this is the target of your MERGE - where the data is supposed to go
   MERGE dbo.Employees AS Target
   -- this is the source where the data to be merged comes from
   USING @closingemployee AS Source
   -- set up a "join" condition for those two sets of data
   ON Target.empid = Source.empid
   -- now define what to do when that JOIN condition matches
   WHEN MATCHED THEN 
       UPDATE 
          SET Target.SomeColumn = Source.Swipepk  --- or WHATEVER you need to update here!
   -- now define what to do when that JOIN condition DOES NOT match (e.g. new employee)
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT(EmpId, CategoryName, Swipepk)
      VALUES(Source.EmpId, Source.CategoryName, Source.Swipepk) ;
END
```

Of course, you can also do other things - and you can define more matching/non-matching criteria, if needed.

This `MERGE` statement is run once and does all the work in a single pass - no looping, no RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) processing - nothing of that sort. One nice, fast, set-based statement and you're done!

**Update:** from your updated question, I see you have **three** major errors in your `MERGE` statement:

```
 WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    BEGIN                                 <=== ERROR #1 : you CANNOT have a BEGIN here!
        UPDATE Target
        SET Target.IsCompleted = N'Y'
        WHERE (Source.swipePK = Target.Swipepk)  <=== ERROR #2 : you CANNOT have 
          AND (Source.empid = Target.empid)                      additional WHERE 
          AND (Target.Date = Source.datetoday)                   clause on the UPDATE

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT INTO Target              <=== ERROR #3: you CANNOT define a INSERT INTO ....
                                      the "INTO" table is already a given by the MERGE
   (empid, Swipin, SwipeOut, Date, Duration, deviceid, InStatus, Outstatus, Invalue, OutValue, IsCompleted, CompletedDate)
    VALUES     (@empid, CONVERT(DATETIME, ' 00:00:00', 102), CONVERT(DATETIME, ' 00:00:00', 102),@datetoday, CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                  ' 00:00:00', 102), 0, N'A', N'A', 0, 0, N'Y',(select GETDATE()) )
```

Comment: ON Target.empid = Source.empid...  i will have prevois days data also on that target table so always employeeid will be there  and this condition will always be true can i put one more condition in it like  Target.empid = Source.empid and Target.date= Source.date

Comment: @sreenathsreenath: you can put **ANY** condition here - it just has to establish a JOIN between the source and target data

Comment: I Pls go trgh edited qstn i had gone through your answer but i had done it but it seems that it says closingemployee cannotbe READONLY  and also invalid datatype

Comment: @sreenathsreenath: sorry - can you please write **entire** words? I have a hard time even *guessing* what you might be saying here.....

Comment: @sreenathsreenath: found **three** major errors in your `MERGE` - once you've fixed these, then maybe it'll work ....

Comment: sorry my English is not good.Thank you for the time you had taken to help me I understood my errors...Can you pls help me or give me a good example on stored procedure ?